# having trouble in downloading file using codeigniter and Ajax

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

i am using codeigniter and ajax for downloading a file.

My Ajax Request

```
    $('.exporter').bind('click',function()
    {
    var callfunction = 'reportprints/print_'+$(this).attr('id').toLowerCase();
    var Query = $('#exportQuery').val();                        
    $.ajax({
    url: callfunction,
    type: 'POST',           
    dataType: 'html',
    data:{q:Query},                                                         
    success: function(output)
    {}
    });
    });
```

it's calling my PDF Function which are in Controller

```
    public function print_pdf()
    {
        $Query = $this->input->post('q');
        // set document information
        $this->pdf->SetAuthor('PrimexOne Exchange');
        $filename = $this->makefilename('pdf','DSP');
        $this->pdf->SetTitle('Daily Sales Report - '.date('d/m/Y'));
        $this->pdf->SetSubject('PrimexOne Sales Report');
        $this->pdf->SetKeywords('keywords');        
        $this->pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'N', 12);   
        // add a page
        //$this->pdf->AddPage();     
        // write html on PDF
        $this->pdf->Cell(0,10,'Welcome in PrimexOne');

        //Creating FileName

        $filepath = APPPATH.'cache/pdfcache/';
        $fullname = $filepath.$filename;
        $this->pdf->Output($fullname, 'F');     
        $this->downloadfile(array('format'=>'pdf','filename'=>$filename,'filepath'=>$fullname));            
    }
```

ajax and PHP perform perfectly and created PDF in pdfcache folder, problem is it's not downloading files when file created.

here is my downloading script

```
    public function downloadfile($arr)
    {

         $mime = 'application/force-download';
           header('Pragma: public');    
           header('Expires: 0');        
           header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
           header('Cache-Control: private',false);
           header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
           header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$arr['filename'].'"');
           header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
           header('Connection: close');
           readfile($arr['filepath']);    
           exit();

    }
```

hope you Genius understand my problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download file through an ajax call php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668776/download-file-through-an-ajax-call-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`application/force-download` is not a mime type.

Try

```
$mime = 'application/pdf';
```

---

```
$('.exporter').bind('click',function(){
    var Query = $('#exportQuery').val();
    var callfunction = 'reportprints/print_'+$(this).attr('id').toLowerCase();
    event.preventDefault();
    var newForm = $('<form>', {
        'action': callfunction,
        'target': '_top'
    }).append($('<input>', {
        'name': 'q',
        'value': Query,
        'type': 'hidden'
    }));
    newForm.submit();
});
```

Comment: i did now it's showing %PDF-1.7
7 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /LastModified (D:20130905152441+02'00') /Resources 2 0 R /MediaBox [0.00 0.00 595.28 841.89] /CropBox [0.00 0.00 595.28 841.89] /BleedBox [0.00 0.00 595.28 841.89] /TrimBox [0.00 0.00 595.28 841.89] /ArtBox [0.00 0.00 595.28 841.89] /Contents 8 0 R /Rotate 0 /Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> /Annots [ 5 0 R ] /PZ 1 >>
endobj
8 0 obj
  etc etc

Comment: Yeah, this isn't going to work (I forgot about the "ajax" part when I answered) without a library or iframe. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1999607/183254 http://stackoverflow.com/q/6668776/183254 There a some good and simple solutions in these links.

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /application/cache/pdfcache/DSP-abuzainab-20130905170415.pdf on this server. what should i don know

Comment: Happy to help. If you still have problems with it (and can't find the solution on google or stackoverflow), just ask another question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
window.location.replace('Your URL Here')
```

And pass the required variables in get.

It will look like normal but works perfectly.

Comment: I have used download library by CI for downloading the file in called function. It will be very easy to use you have to pass file name for downloading pdf and path to pdf `code`force_download('Req File Name.pdf', 'Path to pdf');`code`