# Download pdf file using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf

I want to download a pdf file for jquery ajax response. Ajax response contains pdf file data. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27563953/2368833). My code is given below but I always get a blank pdf.

```
$(document).on('click', '.download-ss-btn', function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/utils/json/pdfGen',
        data: {
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
        }

    }).done(function (data) {
        var blob = new Blob([data]);
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "Sample.pdf";
        link.click();
    });


});
```

Comment: Try substituting `XMLHttpRequest` for `jQuery.ajax()`  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876000/how-to-build-pdf-file-from-binary-string-returned-from-a-web-service-using-javas

Comment: Why do you need to use AJAX for this? Downloading files is much more easily and reliably done without it.

Comment: You can not make pdf with `json` response.It should be a `HTML` response and also it dosn't work on all browser. In given ex. it returns `Url` means a HTML response.

Comment: Here i am using a web service to get formatted pdf file for json data. the response pdf file data start with `%PDF-1.4`

Comment: You have to write code in `success` then `.done` and in which `browser` version you are testing. ` Blob([data])` not working in some browser.

Comment: when i console the data from the ajax response i get the file data properly.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

jQuery has some issues loading binary data using AJAX requests, as it does not yet implement some HTML5 XHR v2 capabilities, see this [enhancement request](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11461) and this [discussion](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1525)

Given that, you have one of two solutions:

**First solution, abandon JQuery and use XMLHTTPRequest**

Go with the native HTMLHTTPRequest, here is the code to do what you need

```
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", "/file.pdf", true);
  req.responseType = "blob";

  req.onload = function (event) {
    var blob = req.response;
    console.log(blob.size);
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download="Dossier_" + new Date() + ".pdf";
    link.click();
  };

  req.send();
```

**Second solution, use the jquery-ajax-native plugin**

The plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/acigna/jquery-ajax-native) and can be used to the XHR V2 capabilities missing in JQuery, here is a sample code how to use it

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'native',
  url: "/file.pdf",
  xhrFields: {
    responseType: 'blob'
  },
  success: function(blob){
    console.log(blob.size);
      var link=document.createElement('a');
      link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download="Dossier_" + new Date() + ".pdf";
      link.click();
  }
});
```

Comment: To make it work in Firefox you have to add 'document.body.appendChild(link);' before clicking the link :)

Comment: Works nicely but I found you will need window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename); to get this working in IE11 as shown by @anonymous.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

  xhrFields: {
    responseType: 'blob'
  },

Comment: InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'blob').

Comment: The first solution worked for me. I have a potential issue with the PDFs though, apparently won't work in Windows Explorer Preview once downloaded, not sure why - but probably a different problem.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.` on Chrome

Comment: The first solution worked for me but after downloading the pdf file when I try to open the file it gives me an error saying that 'Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open... because it is either not a supported file blah blah....'

Answer (score 23):

I am newbie and most of the code is from google search.  I got my pdf download working with the code below (trial and error play). Thank you for code tips (xhrFields) above.

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'yourURL',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: yourdata,
             //xhrFields is what did the trick to read the blob to pdf
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            success: function (response, status, xhr) {

                var filename = "";                   
                var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');

                 if (disposition) {
                    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                    if (matches !== null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                } 
                var linkelem = document.createElement('a');
                try {
                                           var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });                        

                    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                        //   IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                    } else {
                        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                        if (filename) { 
                            // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                            var a = document.createElement("a");

                            // safari doesn't support this yet
                            if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                                window.location = downloadUrl;
                            } else {
                                a.href = downloadUrl;
                                a.download = filename;
                                document.body.appendChild(a);
                                a.target = "_blank";
                                a.click();
                            }
                        } else {
                            window.location = downloadUrl;
                        }
                    }   

                } catch (ex) {
                    console.log(ex);
                } 
            }
        });
```

Comment: you are my HERO. Thank you :)

Comment: 5 hours and about 30 other attributes added to .ajax({})...and xhrFields fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with JavaScript very easily by creating a HTML a tag:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "/WWW/test.pdf";
link.download = "file_" + new Date() + ".pdf";
link.click();
link.remove();
```

Comment: This works. But I don't think that is html5 - this is just javascript - I might be wrong - maybe this code only works in html5? Not sure - but I think there is nothing about that code that is html 5. That is JavaScript DOM manipulation only. That should work in a lot of browsers that support JavaScript to way older versions - perhaps before Html5

Comment: @JohnFoll That's right, I edited the answer

Answer (score 7):

For those looking a more modern approach, you can use the `fetch API`. The following example shows how to download a `PDF` file. It is easily done with the following code.

```
fetch(url, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
})
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(response => {
    const blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = downloadUrl;
    a.download = "file.pdf";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
})
```

I believe this approach to be much easier to understand than other `XMLHttpRequest` solutions. Also, it has a similar syntax to the `jQuery` approach, without the need to add any additional libraries.

Of course, I would advise checking to which browser you are developing, since this new approach won't work on IE. You can find the full browser compatibility list on the following [link][1].

**Important**: In this example I am sending a JSON request to a server listening on the given `url`. This `url` must be set, on my example I am assuming you know this part. Also, consider the headers needed for your request to work. Since I am sending a JSON, I must add the `Content-Type` header and set it to `application/json; charset=utf-8`, as to let the server know the type of request it will receive.

Comment: data is not defined!
but when i remove line 2 it works.

Comment: That’s because you need to define it, unless your request doesn’t required a body.

Comment: The second `.then()` receives a `Blob`, not a `Response`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.download-ss-btn', function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/utils/json/pdfGen',
        data: {
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }

    }).done(function (data) {
        let binaryString = window.atob(data);
        let binaryLen = binaryString.length;
        let bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);

        for (let i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
            let ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
            bytes[i] = ascii;
        }
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"});
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "Sample.pdf";
        link.click();
    });
});
```