# Failed to load PDF document in web api

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke

I am getting error while downloading and opening pdf files as

> Failed to load PDF document

. But when i tried to download txt file it gets download success fully. I need to this ajax request to be as POST method, So after searching in internet i found this code.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: function (data) {

    var blob = new Blob([data]);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = textName;
    link.click();
}, error: function (data) { alert("error"); }});
```

I use web api for downloading the file

```
public HttpResponseMessage Download(string fileName)
{   
    string filePath = Path.Combine(PATH, fileName.Replace('/', '\\'));
    byte[] pdf = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    HttpResponseMessage result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pdf);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "MyPdf.pdf";
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    return result;
}
```

Please help me

Comment: What if you specify the mime type in the `Blob` constructor? `var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });`

Comment: yup , i tried that too :(

Comment: What browser are you using? On what line is the error thrown?

Comment: I am using **Google chrome**. I am not getting any error while downloading. Pdf file get downloaded and while opening that it shows error as **Failed to Load PDF**

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [Download pdf file using jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34587987/5233410)

> jQuery has some issues loading binary data using AJAX requests, as it
>   does not yet implement some HTML5 XHR v2 capabilities

It provides two options for you try. I won't repeat them here as they belong to that answer. Check the link.

On the server side, I've had success downloading PDF files using this method.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Download(string fileName)
{   
    string filePath = Path.Combine(PATH, fileName.Replace('/', '\\'));
    byte[] pdf = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    //content length for header
    var contentLength = pdf.Length;
    var statuscode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    var result = Request.CreateResponse(statuscode);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(buffer));
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength;
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "MyPdf.pdf";

    return result;
}
```

Not that much different to your original.

You should also check to make sure that the original file was not corrupt on the server if you are reading from disk/database or if you are dynamically generating the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably your Content-Disposition header. You need inline, but you have attachment.

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
```

What you have now tells the browser to specifically send the file directly, and never attempt to display it in-browser. Chrome's internal PDF viewer currently chokes when you do this.

More: [Content-Disposition:What are the differences between "inline" and "attachment"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment)