# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in mvc while downloading pdf document

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to view a pdf document from memorystream in a new window.but some error are showing like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %"

here is my code

```
public ActionResult ViewDocument()
        {
    byte[] FileArr = fileRepo.GetBlockByte();
                    MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream(FileArr);
                    byte[] byteInfo = pdfStream .ToArray();
                    pdfStream .Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
                    pdfStream .Position = 0;
                    return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream , "application/pdf");
}
```

can any one help actually why this error occur?

Thanks in advance

Comment: that sounds like a javascript error - where's this called from?

Comment: it is calling from an ajax call.

$.ajax({
            url: $(document.body).data('url') + 'Reports/ViewDocument',
            type: 'POST',
            //contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function () {

            },
            complete: function () {

            }
        });

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586671/download-pdf-file-using-jquery-ajax