# Download DOCX documents using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, download, docx

I am using the following js script to post variables from a web form to a python script which then generates a docx documents and in turn responds back to the ajax POST to download it, I can successfully get a file however it seems corrupt when trying to open with word(possibly due to mis-encoding), the size of the file is around 300K, but when downloaded the size is 500K

The reason I would like to use the ajax script is so that I can get a full handle of the situation, sometimes the server side python script returns an error and I would like to use ajax to display this to the user to understand what is going on.

How can I modify the js script to properly save the docx file. I have tried different `dataType` for the ajax post, but I get parse error when using anything but `text` type.

**Code:**

```
var url = $('#myform').attr('action');

var data = $('#myform').serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(responseData,textStatus, xhr)
    {
        console.log('got response' + textStatus + xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition"));
        var blob=new Blob([responseData],{type:"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"});
        var link=document.createElement('a');
        link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download="test.docx";
        link.click();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) 
    {
         var msg = '';
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            msg = 'Time out error.';
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
        } else {
            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        console.log(msg);
    } 

})
```

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657184/using-jquerys-ajax-method-to-retrieve-images-as-a-blob)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a somewhat known issue with jQuery, it can corrupt binary files, because of an intermediate conversion to string.

Nevertheless, check the solutions that are provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586671/download-pdf-file-using-jquery-ajax/34587987#34587987). If that does not suite your needs then you may want to use [this](http://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html) fix.