# HTML anchor tag's onclick not working with REST GET API call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying the below code to call a REST GET API on click of `href`. I need to send my custom headers in the HTTP GET request. I want the pdf file returned by GET API to be opened in a new tab in the browser when the `href` is clicked while the original page stays as is in its tab.

When I use the code below, it opens the same page URL in a new tab. When I look at the Network call made under browser's Javascript console, it does show that the API was invoked with the required headers. But the browser itself doesn't display that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> A jQuery click href </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click_href').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myserver:8080/path/download?a=A&b=B&filename=file.pdf',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'pdf',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('CLIENT_ID', 'WEB_APP');
        },
        success: function (response) {
            
        }
    })
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1> Demonstration for jQuery click href </h1>
<a href="#" id="click_href" target="_blank">Test by Curious Brain</a>
</body>
</html>
```

### UPDATE

This is how the PDF is returned by Spring Boot REST controller. If I try the direct download URL in a browser window, the PDF is displayed in the browser.

```
@CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(path = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(
            @RequestParam("a") String a,
            @RequestParam("b") String b,
            @RequestParam("filename") String fileName) throws IOException {

        FileSystemResource pdfFile = new FileSystemResource(reportBaseDir + "/" + a + "/" + b + "/" + fileName);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE));
        headers.setAccessControlAllowMethods(Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.GET));
        headers.setAccessControlAllowHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type"));
        headers.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.builder("inline").filename(fileName).build());
        headers.setCacheControl("no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.setPragma("no-cache");
        headers.setExpires(0L);
        headers.setContentLength(pdfFile.contentLength());

        return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(
                new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Following the responses given below, I updated my HTML code to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> A jQuery click href </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click_href').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myserver:8080/path/download?a=A&b=B&filename=file.pdf',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'pdf',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('CLIENT_ID', 'WEB_APP');
        },
        success: function (response) {
            window.open("data:application/pdf," + escape(response), '_blank');
        }
    })
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1> Demonstration for jQuery click href </h1>
<a href="#" id="click_href">Test by Curious Brain</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Even then, I can see that a call is made to the download URL but nothing happens. I want the pdf file to be displayed in a new tab in the browser when the href link is clicked.**

Network trace from browser's Javascript console:

```
Summary
URL: http://myserver:8080/path/download?a=A&b=B&filename=file.pdf
Status: 200
Source: Network
Address: <some ip>:8080
Initiator: 
jquery.min.js:2:82618


Request
GET /path/download HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: null
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: myserver:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.1 Safari/605.1.15
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
CLIENT_ID: WEB_APP

Response
HTTP/1.1 200
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/pdf
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="file.pdf"
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Date: Thu, 13 Jan 2022 21:19:02 GMT
Content-Length: 387717
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers

Query String Parameters
a: A
b: B
filename: file.pdf
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This is the closest I could bring this to. But this only downloads the file. I tried `window.open(…)` but that doesn’t open the file in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> A jQuery click href </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click_href').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            //cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http:/myserver:8080/path/download?a=A&b=B&filename=file.pdf',
            //contentType: false,
            //processData: false,
            data: 'native',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('CLIENT_ID', 'WEB_APP');
            },
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            success: function (response, status, xhr) {

                var filename = '';                   
                var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                alert(disposition);

                if (disposition) {
                    filename = disposition.split('"')[1];
                    alert(filename);
                }
                
                var linkelem = document.createElement('a');
                
                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });                        
            
                var downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.target = "_blank";
                //window.open(a);
                a.click();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1> Demonstration for jQuery click href </h1>
<a href="#" id="click_href">Test by Curious Brain</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I run that last bit of code (the one supposed to open the PDF) with some random pdf fille, it gets open correctly in the browser. So there must be something funky with your PDF's or with the way you're serving them. I haven't been able to repro the issue, which indicates the problem might not be with the code you've shown so far. Could you create a *runnable* [mcve]?

Comment: I got it to work. The problem was the ```application/octet-stream``` in JavaScript code. The mime type forces the file to be downloaded. When I changed it to ```application/pdf``` file opened in the browser instead of downloading. I will post the complete solution and findings shortly. The one funky thing that remains a mystery (and not critical to my requirement, as such) is that the browser address bar display ```blob:null/6af2f4a4-ca4d-42fa-9962-c54ae3cd357c``` and I am not sure how to get that to display the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got it to work. Pay attention to code comments

As a repeat, the requirement was to get a PDF file from REST GET API and display in the browser but also adding some custom HTTP headers in the request (`CLIENT_ID, WEB_APP`)

### Spring Boot Rest Controller

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(
    @RequestParam("a") String a,
    @RequestParam("b") String b,
    @RequestParam("filename") String fileName) throws IOException {
        FileSystemResource pdfFile = new FileSystemResource(a + "/" + b + "/" + fileName);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE));
        //Since you already have the controller annotated with @CrossOrigin, you don't need the below line. Keeping this makes browsers complain that Access-Control-Allow-Origin has two '*', '*' values
        //headers.setAccessControlAllowOrigin("*");
        headers.setAccessControlAllowMethods(Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.GET));
        headers.setAccessControlAllowHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type"));
        //has to be 'inline' if you want to display the PDF file in the browserheaders.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.builder("inline").filename(fileName).build());
        headers.setCacheControl("no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.setPragma("no-cache");
        headers.setExpires(0L);
        headers.setContentLength(pdfFile.contentLength());
        //Add the headers that you want to get via xhr.getResponseHeader() in JavaScript; without this, the value returned would be null  headers.setAccessControlExposeHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Disposition"));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> A jQuery click href </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click_href').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            //cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://myserver:8080/path/download?a=A&b=B&filename=file.pdf',
            //contentType: false,
            //processData: false,
            //data: 'native',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('CLIENT_ID', 'WEB_APP');
            },
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob' // important to be set to make this work
            },
            success: function (response, status, xhr) {

                var filename = '';                   
                var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');

                if (disposition) {
                    filename = disposition.split('"')[1];
                }
                // if this is application/octet-stream, the file will be forced to be downloaded instead of opening in the browser; make sure this is application/pdf
                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            
                var downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                //a.download = filename;
                //document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.target = "_blank";
                //window.open(a);
                a.click();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1> Demonstration for jQuery click href </h1>
<a href="#" id="click_href">Test by Curious Brain</a>
</body>
</html>
```

### Network trace

```
Summary
URL: http://myserver:8080/path/download?a=A&b=B&filename=file.pdf
Status: 200
Source: Network
Address: <ip redacted>:8080
Initiator: 
jquery.min.js:2:82618


Request
GET /path/download HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: null
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: myserver:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.2 Safari/605.1.15
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
CLIENT_ID: WEB_APP

Response
HTTP/1.1 200
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/pdf
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="file.pdf"
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Date: Fri, 14 Jan 2022 16:58:44 GMT
Content-Length: 397295
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers

Query String Parameters
a: A
b: B
filename: file.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser is opening the current page in a new window because that is what the link does.

`href="#"` means "the top of the current page" and `target="_blank"` means "in a new window or tab".

The JavaScript isn't calling `preventDefault` on the event object, so that behaviour isn't prevented.

---

The Ajax request is a completely separate HTTP request which you run when the link is clicked.

It makes the HTTP request.

The data is returned to JS.

The `success` function is run.

The data is passed into the `response` variable.

And then you do … nothing.

If you want to do something with the data from the Ajax request then you have to actually do *something*.

Perhaps something along the lines of [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999607/download-and-open-pdf-file-using-ajax).

Comment: I tried your suggestion and a couple of things from the link you gave. But every time, the PDF is neither displayed in browser nor downloaded. My requirement is to display the PDF in a new tab in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what response is return by your API call, if its returning the pdf file path then you can simply make use of window.open();

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click_href').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // this is to stop your page from reloading
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myserver:8080/path/download?a=A&b=B&filename=file.pdf',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'pdf',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('CLIENT_ID', 'WEB_APP');
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // If your response if url then you can use
            window.open(response, '_blank');

           // IF your response is base64 PDF data then you can use something like 
          window.open("data:application/pdf," + escape(response), '_blank'); 

        }
    })
    });
});
</script>
```

Also you need to remove target="_blank" from your original a tag

Comment: Hi Swapnil, I tried what you suggested and updated my question. But every time, the PDF is neither displayed in browser nor downloaded. My requirement is to display the PDF in a new tab in the browser.