# Trouble exporting csv using Maatwebsite\Excel Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel-9, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm trying to export a csv file with Maatwebsite\Excel and Laravel 9.

As a response, I get my datas and headings in console > network , but no download occurs.

Here's my code :

Exports

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\Data;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;


class DataExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return Data::all();
    }

    public function headings():array{
        return[
           Schema::getColumnListing('data') 
        ];
    }
}
```

And my controller (1st try) :

```
public function download_file_csv()
{
    Excel::store(new DataExport, 'dataTemplate.csv');
    Excel::download(new DataExport,'dataTemplate.csv',\Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::CSV, [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
    ]);
}
```

and 2nd try

```
public function download_file_csv()
{
    Excel::store(new DataExport, 'dataTemplate.csv');
    return Excel::download(new DataExport,'dataTemplate.csv');
}
```

The file with datas and headings is properly stored in my public folder...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The command looks okay. Is the return statement in `download_file_csv()` being sent as a response? If you are calling it from another method, it must be returned again, all the way until it is sent as a response.

Comment: @matticustard  , my datas are displayed in the network > response section of the console . So i think that yes. How can I be sure ? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to download an AJAX response? If so, this requires additional JS code on the client side, as downloading a file normally requires opening a new page. All of the code provided above is from the server side. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27563953/5309998

Comment: @matticustard, thanks !  Yes, close : i'm trying to download my file from a fetch response. I tried to download the file from a link and clicking on it with js without success (file not found although it's present in the folder). Can you help me with the code on the client side pls ?